# How to prevent echo some char in fgets

Tags: c, shell, echo, fgets

I am using fgets to read the user input. But if I am press "Ctrl+C", I will get a ^C char on the terminal. I am wandering if there is any way to prevent this echo?

Comment: That's a terminal setting, nothing directly to do with "fgets()" or C stdio.  SUGGESTION: you can control terminal behavior (including implement cursor movement, accept per-key input, etc etc) by using [ncurses](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).

Answer (score 1):

If all you're missing is to keep the ^C from showing up on the screen, use curses to disable echo:

```
#include <ncurses.h>                                                              
#include <stdlib.h>                                                               

void main() {                                                                     
    char buf[90];                                                                 
    initscr();                                                                    
    noecho();                                                                     
    fgets(buf, 80, stdin);                                                        
}
```

Comment: You will have to compile with -lcurses to link against the curses library.

Comment: ncurses , will work , but the library should be downloaded separately.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL-C is used to abort the current task and regain user control. It is a special sequence which causes the operating system to send a signal to the active program.

The default action of the CTRL-C signal is to terminate the active program , whether or not it is executing fgets().
  One way to override this , is to write your own signal handler and ignore CTRL-C , inside your program , which i doubt will serve your purpose be of any benefit to you.

Comment: Kernel is not concerned with Ctrl+C in any way. It is a terminal emulator who sends a SIGINT to the controlled process.

Comment: @VladLazarenko , ya SIGINT between the two programs , tty and the user process , the signal bitfield is usually stored in the pid's of these processes...

Comment: Yes I am writing an interactive shell, its SIGINT handler will catch CTRL-C signal and terminates any foreground process, but if there is no process running, my program will wait for the user input. And at this time if I press CTRL-C, "^c" will show on the console as part of my input. I am not sure how to do what you said in the handler?

Comment: @user2138159 , writing an empty signal handler for SIGINT , is sufficient for the process to drop the signal , and not get terminated (which is the default action , if you have not installed any signal handler)